# SQL Query to return 2 results for multiple employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, navicat

I am very new to SQL and in fact, I am completely self taught. I currently have this query below which works to find (badly) 2 random support tickets by employee.

Right now, the query will ask the employees name and provide 2 results. Is there a way to have this provide 2 results for ALL employees?

```
SELECT
        TOP 2 CONVERT (
            DATE,
            SD_REQUEST.END_DATE_UT
        ) AS 'Close Date',
        SD_REQUEST.RFC_number AS 'Ticket',
        agent.LAST_NAME AS 'Agent',
        AM_DOMAIN.NAME_EN AS 'Company',
        EE.LAST_NAME AS 'Recipient',
        RR.LAST_NAME AS 'Requestor',
        catpath.SD_CATALOG_PATH_EN
    FROM
        SD_REQUEST
    LEFT JOIN AM_EMPLOYEE AS agent ON agent.EMPLOYEE_ID = SD_REQUEST.OWNER_ID
    LEFT JOIN AM_EMPLOYEE AS EE ON EE.EMPLOYEE_ID = SD_REQUEST.RECIPIENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN AM_EMPLOYEE AS RR ON RR.EMPLOYEE_ID = SD_REQUEST.REQUESTOR_ID
    LEFT JOIN SD_CATALOG_PATH AS catpath ON catpath.SD_CATALOG_ID = SD_REQUEST.SD_CATALOG_ID
    LEFT JOIN AM_DOMAIN ON AM_DOMAIN.DOMAIN_ID = EE.DEFAULT_DOMAIN_ID
    WHERE
        agent.LAST_NAME = 'insert name here'
    AND CONVERT (
        datetime,
        SD_REQUEST.END_DATE_UT,
        101
    ) BETWEEN (Getdate() - 8)
    AND (Getdate() - 2)
    ORDER BY
        NEWID()
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Question is tagged MySQL.

Comment: remove `agent.LAST_NAME = 'insert name here'
    AND` and it will give you everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server based on syntax in question.  You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function inside a cte/subquery to generate a number for each row, using `PARTITION BY` you can have the numbering start over for each member of a given set/group, in this case `agent.LAST_NAME`, you can use that number to limit to two results per set/group:

```
;with cte AS (
        SELECT  CONVERT (DATE,SD_REQUEST.END_DATE_UT) AS 'Close Date',
                SD_REQUEST.RFC_number AS 'Ticket',
                agent.LAST_NAME AS 'Agent',
                AM_DOMAIN.NAME_EN AS 'Company',
                EE.LAST_NAME AS 'Recipient',
                RR.LAST_NAME AS 'Requestor',
                catpath.SD_CATALOG_PATH_EN,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY agent.LAST_NAME ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN
            FROM
                SD_REQUEST
            LEFT JOIN AM_EMPLOYEE AS agent ON agent.EMPLOYEE_ID = SD_REQUEST.OWNER_ID
            LEFT JOIN AM_EMPLOYEE AS EE ON EE.EMPLOYEE_ID = SD_REQUEST.RECIPIENT_ID
            LEFT JOIN AM_EMPLOYEE AS RR ON RR.EMPLOYEE_ID = SD_REQUEST.REQUESTOR_ID
            LEFT JOIN SD_CATALOG_PATH AS catpath ON catpath.SD_CATALOG_ID = SD_REQUEST.SD_CATALOG_ID
            LEFT JOIN AM_DOMAIN ON AM_DOMAIN.DOMAIN_ID = EE.DEFAULT_DOMAIN_ID
        WHERE  CONVERT (datetime,SD_REQUEST.END_DATE_UT,101) BETWEEN (Getdate() - 8) AND (Getdate() - 2)
        )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RN <= 2
```